# Simulating sum of squared brownian motions process

Tags: programming, stochastic-processes, simulations, sde

I'm trying to simulate the following stochastic process:

\begin{equation}
R_t = \sum_{i=1}^nB_{i,t}^2
\end{equation}

which has the following dynamics:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    dR_t = \sum_{i=1}^n 2B_{i,t}dB_{i,t} + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n 2 dt \\
    = ndt + \sum_{i=1}^n 2B_{i,t}dB_{i,t} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

for this I created a function that simulates the brownian motion process and then calculated the dymacis of the process:

```
def brownian_motion(T: int, steps: int, n_sim: int):
    dt = T/steps
    dBt =  np.column_stack([np.random.normal(0, math.sqrt(dt), n_sim) for _ in range(steps+1)])
    dBt[:, 0] = 0
    Bt = dBt.cumsum(1)

    return Bt[:, :steps], dBt[:, :steps]

def bessel_process(dimensions: int, Z0: float, T: int, steps: int, n_sim: int) -> (np.array, np.array):
    summation = np.zeros([n_sim, steps])
    
    for _ in range(dimensions):
        Bt, dBt = brownian_motion(T, steps, n_sim) 
        summation += Bt * dBt * 2
        
    dRt = summation + dimensions * T/steps
    Rt = dRt.cumsum(1)
    
    return Rt, np.sqrt(Rt)
```

The problem is that the resulting process has a mean 3 times the expected and I can't figure out where is the error in my code.

Comment: Hi: I'm not clear on wha the Bt, dBt = brownian_motion line does but the dBt is the change in the brownian motion which is Bt so maybe that's where the problem is ? Are you calling the brownian_motion function twice ? I'm out the rest of the day but hopefully this helps in some way.

Comment: The `brownian_motion` function creates a brownian motion process and the `Bt * dBt *2` is the part of the process dynamic

Comment: Hi: I see now what you're doing in the brownian_motion function so that seems correct to me. I don't have time right now to carefully look at the rest of it. Maybe someone else can help here ?